# How to make a picklist input field as required in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, administration, required-field

Making a picklist field as *required* means to remove the `--None--` option.

A picklist cannot be made `required` in the field setup.

In a standard detail page, a picklist can be made *required* by checking the `Required` checkbox in the page layout. This removes the `--None--` option from the picklist options.

However, in a Visualforce page, an  picklist cannot be made *required* with `required="true"`, even if the picklist has a default value specified in setup.

### How to make a picklist input field as required in a Visualforce page?

I do not want to resort to dirty Java Script code unless there is no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the new Winter 17 release existing custom picklist fields can now be marked as required at a field level.

[image]

> To create or modify custom picklists:
>
> Picklist on an object — Use the fields area of the object.
>
> Global picklist — From Setup, enter picklist in the Quick Find box, then select > Picklists.

Taken from the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_picklists_make_existing_required.htm) for Winter 17.

Answer (score 4):

Use Validation Rule to make it required.

`ISBLANK(ShippingCountry)` an example .

In visualforce you will need to catch error from validation in controller and use

```
 ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Please select a value'));
     return null;
```

Then use`<apex:Pagemessages/>` in Visualforce.